# How can I remove the ASP.NET Session ID from my URL?

Tags: asp.net, url, cookies

How can I remove the identifier from my URL?

In this example URL I need just `index.aspx`, how do I remove `(S(w0uz0245gtucb3am0k5w5g55))`?

> http://www.example.com/(S(w0uz0245gtucb3am0k5w5g55))/index.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Your webserver is rewriting your urls to include the session state because you have configured your site to not use cookies.

If you look at your site's `web.config` file, you will probably find this line:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

If you change the value to "false" if will solve your problem (or just remove the line entirely - the default value is false)

More information about this configuration can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you understand what it is, but I did it for browsers, which do not support cookies by default. But I need somehow to identify users. Is is possible to exclude cookie value from link and to use in session variable for example or what I have to do?

Comment: @Sergej: The SessionID is already availabe using `Session.SessionID`. But Sessions are server side, which is why the cookie is needed. Otherwise, ASP.NET cannot verify 2 requests are from the same, or different devices.

Comment: Is it possible to save strange url to session variable and not to show in url at all with asp.net? I use pure asp.net code. Maybe dotnetnuke cms helps me with it?  But I just want to find the code how to make it..

Comment: Helped me Thanks ... Please approve this answer

Answer (score -3):

You could wrap your entire application in an iFrame.  Nobody would see the long URL.

Comment: Please do not do this